# How I can change the orient of labels on echarts4r?

Tags: r, echarts4r

Hi and thanks for reading this. I am trying to make a bar plot with value labels on `echarts4r`, but I can't change the orientation of the labels so that the values do not overlap. I tried `orient = "vertical"` but it doesn't work. My code is as follows:

```
library(echarts4r)
library(dplyr)

mtcars |> 
  tibble::rownames_to_column("model") |> 
  mutate(cyl2 = cyl*10000) |> 
  e_charts(model) |> 
  e_bar(cyl2,
        label = list(
          show = TRUE,
          position = "top",
          orient = "vertical",
          textStyle = list(fontFamily = "Roboto Condensed", 
                           fontSize = 12)
        ))
```

Is there a way to change the orientation of the labels? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set the orientation of the value labels via the `rotation` parameter. Depending on your desired result you also have to set the `verticalAlignment` and the horizontal `align`ment:

```
library(echarts4r)
library(dplyr)

mtcars |> 
  tibble::rownames_to_column("model") |> 
  mutate(cyl2 = cyl*10000) |> 
  e_charts(model) |> 
  e_bar(cyl2,
        label = list(
          show = TRUE,
          position = "top",
          rotate = 90,
          verticalAlign = "middle",
          align = "left",
          textStyle = list(fontFamily = "Roboto Condensed", 
                           fontSize = 12)
        ))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works